# Port forwarding issue from public ip to local ip

Tags: routing, port-forwarding

Hi all I have a cisco router with Public IP and a port open on 8007 toward 192.168.1.18.
Local ip for cisco is 192.168.1.1

I have connected another asus router to the cisco. -> ip 192.168.1.18
The asus router creates another local network with ip 192.168.2.1
On this network there is a computer 192.168.2.17 which i want the port 8007 to be used.

Is that correct i have to use port forward in the asus ruter? Or this is like the forwarding is only working if on the same network segment?
is it correct I am using nmap in order to check if port is open on 192.168.2.17?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that correct i have to use port forward in the asus ruter?

No, this should not be necessary since your Asus router should not be using NAT between internal subnets.

> Or this is like the forwarding is only working if on the same network segment?

No, so long as the Asus router advertises to the Cisco that it has a route to your second subnet, the Cisco will route traffic correctly via the Asus

---

It is quite likely that a simpler and therefore more reliable solution is to remove the Asus router and configure the Cisco to do the job of routing between two internal subnets using two of its RJ45 ports.

Unless the Asus is doing something very special, I'd consider this.

Comment: I would bet that neither the Asus nor the Cisco actually speak any of the usual protocols for "advertising" a route, and that in reality OP just has two layers of NAT...

Comment: @user1686: I agree that is moderately likely. You can configure static routes in such a case but I'd simplify the situation by eliminating the least capable router if possible.